# Pass a logger to a static class

Tags: c#

I have a static class in the production. For some reason, we need to replace the logging part methods in this class.(Still a static class unchanged)

Now I want to pass a logger to it. The logger is from another class.

```
public static class OutputUtils   
public static void LogInfo(string logMessage)
{
    logger.LogInfo(logMessage);
}
```

In another class, I have

```
private readonly ILogger _logger;
public AnotherClass(ILogger logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}
internal static void LogDebug(string logMessage)
{
    OutputUtils.LogInfo(logMessage);
}
```

Yes, I want to pass `_logger` to the static class `OutputUtils`.
How?

Comment: Do you plan on doing this once or each time you log?  Keep in mind this won't be thread-safe at all

Comment: This seems like a design mistake. Are you sure that's what you want to do?

Comment: you'll need to pass the logger as well as your mesage. The call to `OutputUtils.LogInfo` seems rather redundant as `AnotherClass` already has the logger you want to use. The same results will be achieved by invoking `_logger.LogInfo(logMessage)` from `AnotherClass.LogDebug`.

Comment: @Slugart, the static class is a base utility(sort of framework).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest change is to add the logger as a parameter:

```
public static void LogInfo(ILogger logger, string logMessage)
{
    logger.LogInfo(logMessage);
}
```

I would *not* add a static property to the class, because then you have to consider thread-safety if multiple clients try to set the property.  You could then have race conditions if one thread sets the logger, another thread sets the property to some other logger, and the first thread calls `LogInfo`, which would output to the *other* thread's logger.

But what's the purpose of the method at all?  Why doesn't the client just call `logger.LogInfo(logMessage)`?

Comment: In theory, client call is possible. But the static class is in the production(it won't be changed as non-static), there are 400 more reference it. In all methods, it is referenced. And also my ILogger is created by NLOG. I heard that it can overcome the race conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Following code can be used for adding logger in static classes

```
private static void TemporaryLogger(string methodName, string lineNumber)
    {
        var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder => builder.AddConsole());
        var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(string.Empty);
        logger.LogInformation($"Test Logger for className class: Identifier - {methodName} : Line number - {lineNumber}");
    }
```